# Update Multiple Rows at once MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which includes a row for each day of the week.

Each row contains 2 input fields.

[image]

I am wanting to click one save button which will update all rows from the table into seperate MySQL rows.

I have the below code to insert new rows (which works fine) but wondering how this can be changed to an UPDATE statement?

```
 $insertArr = array();
    for ($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++) {
        $insertArr[] = "('" 
            . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Actual'][$i]) .
            "', '" 
            . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Period'][$i]) .
            "', '" 
            . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['AddedBy'][$i]) .
                "', '" 
            . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Date'][$i]) .
                "', '" 
            . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Employee'][$i]) .
                "', '" 
            . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Rotered'][$i]) . "')";
}



 $query = "INSERT INTO hr_employee_rostered_hours (Actual, PeriodID, AddedBy, DateOfHours, EmployeeUniqueID, Rotered) VALUES " . implode(", ", $insertArr);
 mysql_query($query) or trigger_error("Insert failed: " . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Deprecated: The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: check this https://github.com/keephacking/new-insights/blob/master/include/table.class.php for mysqli examples

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The mysql extension has been deprecated in PHP, and I strongly advice against using it.

Assuming that you're still getting the values that you want to update using the array,

[Here is](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) a link about PDO (not official docummentation) that helped me out when I first started with PHP and PDO

Here's an example using PDO

```
$updateq = "UPDATE hr_employee_rostered_hours SET (Actual = :actualvalue, PeriodID = :periodid, AddedBy = :addedby,DateOfHours = :dateofhrs, Rotered = :rotered ) WHERE EmployeeUniqueID = :employeeid";
$updatex = $dbh->prepare($updateq);
$updatex->bindValue(":actualvalue",$insertArr[0]);
$updatex->bindValue(":periodid",$insertArr[1]);
$updatex->bindValue(":addedby",$insertArr[2]);
$updatex->bindValue(":dateofhrs",$insertArr[3]);
$updatex->bindValue(":periodid",$insertArr[5]);
$updatex->bindValue(":employeeid",$insertArr[4]);
$updatex->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you Elanor. I will give this a try. I'm new to PDO.

Comment: Maybe also do a check to make sure the execute() returned true and not false. Just for debugging purposes

Comment: yup, Im just giving him a general structure of pdo and binding values for him to work with

Comment: Elanor. Thank you again. However, I'm not sure how I should be declaring the values? (Actual, Periodid, addedby etc)?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by that?
Based on your code, what I see is that you are somehow putting them into an array, and then imploding the array to form a string.
What I did was simply to pull the value out from the array instead of imploding them, and binded them to the query itself

Comment: So, from my code in the question, do i simply replace the query with your answer above?

Comment: For the update case, yes.
You'll also need to set up a PDO connection string, thats what $dbh is supposed to be

Comment: Hmm, I have done this and still just getting the 'This page isn’t working' error

Comment: Do you have the full error?
It's pretty hard to tell what's not working on my end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157455/discussion-between-shane-and-elanor).

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code to update in MySQL.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($insertArr); $i++){
   $var_to_update = implode(", ", $insertArr[$i]);

   $actual = $var_to_update[0];
   $periodID = $var_to_update[1];
   $addedby = $var_to_update[2];
   $dateofhour = $var_to_update[3];
   $employeeUniqueID = $var_to_update[4];
   $rotered = $var_to_update[5];

   $query = "UPDATE hr_employee_rostered_hours SET (Actual = $actual , PeriodID = $periodID, AddedBy = $addedby, DateOfHours = $dateofhour, EmployeeUniqueID = $employeeUniqueID, Rotered = $rotered) WHERE EmployeeUniqueID = $employeeUniqueID";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);

   if ($result === FALSE) 
   {
    die(mysql_error());
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, where would this fit/replace into my code above?

Comment: Thanks, however it doesnt seem to be doing anything?

Comment: This code is working. You just have to place it on right place

Comment: I have added it after         `. mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Rotered'][$i]) . "')";}`
- is this right?

Comment: I just see `Query was empty`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157456/discussion-between-shane-and-muhammad-wajahat-anwar).

Comment: I still see 'Query Was Empty'